# Python memory profiler with Sonarqube & Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, testing, memory, sonarqube

I am evaluating python memory profiling. I would like to automate memory leak profiling with Jenkins and publish the report to Sonarqube. The current memory tool I am using is memory_profiler. Does Jenkins & Sonarqube support this integration? Or are there any python memory tools which I should consider which can integrate well into Jenkins & Sonarqube? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think Sonarqube supports that. 
The only thing that I see you could do, is to run the memory profiler as you are doing, but instead of uploading to sonarqube as per your approach, you could create a html report from the memory profiler results and attach it to your Jenkins build.